# iOS Airprint Print Automatically Without Selecting Printer

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Building a Kiosk app under enterprise account. Don't care if we have to use undocumented APIs, I need some way to print automatically without the user having to interact with a dialog. Any way to do this? So far everything I have read says that there is no way - but it doesn't necessarily have to meet app store guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 8 or newer, use printToPrinter. iOS API docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPrintInteractionController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010141-CH1-SW34

I have an app using this in the store.

Comment: Please write a good answer, wait until you get and upvote and then mark other questions where you posted the exact same answer as duplicates of the question where the good answer is. Please don't post the same question across multiple questions. If those are not duplicates then adjust every answer to be specific to that question.